# UIButton in UITableViewCell not responding in iOS 5x but responding in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, uibutton, ios6

I have a button I'm adding in a UITableViewCell programmatically and it is behaving very strangely.

In iOS 6 it works exactly as expected.  In iOS 5x it only responds to touch-down events and not touch-up-inside events.  And even the touch down event only fires after you hold down for a second or two.

```
//Create UIButton
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

//Add to UITableViewCell
UITableViewCell *footerCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"FOOTER_CELL"] autorelease];
[footerCell.contentView addSubview:button];
//Also tried this with just [footerCell addSubview:button];

//Fire Action
- (void)buttonTap {
    NSLog(@"Tap");
}
```

Pretty standard issue code.  In fact I use this exact code to make buttons all over the place in my app and they all work, except in the table view.  There's got to be something I'm not understanding about the structure of the cell.

Comment: Could it be something interesting like a tableView on another scrollView ?

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me both in iOS 5.x and iOS 6 when i add the button in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I take it for some reason you need to add the button in the cell somewhere else, not in the data source method. Why are you not using cellForRowAtIndexPath to get the cell and then add the button in it? Maybe that could make a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it figured out.  Long long ago I had put a UITapGestureRecognizer on the table for another reason.  It was interfering with the button's functionality.  Thanks guys.  (and gals)